# Sharepoint 2013 ribbon greyed out

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

i wanted to make a survey in SharePoint 2013, but, didnt want users to see results so i cut the following

> SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplaterunat="server" FeatureScope="Site"
>               Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
>               GroupId="ActionsMenuForSurvey"
>               UseShortId="true"
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   runat="server"

from C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\DefaultTemplates and was ok. After 
server restart I noticed that even if i have admin rights i cant upload document, create new folder, use library setting etc. So i copy it back and saved it but things are the same. I have admin rights